# Vite glob import - accessing body / payload in SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm using the glob import functionality of Vite to bring in multiple markdown files to a SvelteKit page:

```js
<script context="module">
    export async function load() {
        const employmentsMeta =
            import.meta.globEager('./employments/*.md');
        return {
            props: {
                employmentsMeta: employmentsMeta
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let employmentsMeta;
</script>
```

This works well for me to access the metadata via `employmentsMeta[Object.keys(employmentsMeta)[0]]['metadata']`. I'm having difficulty accessing the actual contents of the markdown file, however - no matter how I attempt to access it, it seems to be coming back as undefined.

For example, `console.log(employmentsMeta[Object.keys(employmentsMeta)[0]['default']])` returns undefined, despite my understanding that there's a default export object in there, and the metadata access working as intended.

How do I access the payload / body of the imported markdown?

Comment: Vite doc: "Vite supports importing multiple modules from the file system via the special import.meta.glob function:" A .md file is not a module.

Comment: Glob import is in the SvelteKit API and the primary use case seems to be for importing `.md` files.

Comment: did you come up with a solution to get the content of the MD file?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use-case, with markdown files in SvelteKit as blog posts.

In your example, I'd get the file contents as html like this:

```js
const contents = employmentsMeta[Object.keys(employmentsMeta)[0]].default.render();
```

`contents` here is an object like this:

```js
{
  html: '/* a string with the markdown content parsed as html */',
  css: { code: '', map: null },
  head: '',
}
```

I guess you have to use mdsvex for the md->html conversion to happen.

EDIT: I should mention that I do this in an *endpoint* ([slug].json.js), return the results, and get them in the route, as doing it in the `load` function was throwing an error (`...default.render is not a function`) client-side.